# Cybersource ACH payment method order tracking

Tags: php, soap, payment-gateway

I am creating ACH payment method for Cybersource in Magento (PHP). I have completed order placing & subscription process with SOAP api , but i am facing issue for order tracking because as nature of ACH (echeck) payment method taking 3 or 5 days to complete.  It will also reject due to insufficient funds. I have made SOAP api call but its giving me error like **"The following request field(s) is either invalid or missing: ics_applications "**

below is my code snippet for tracking order :

```
$ecDebitReply = new stdClass();
$ecDebitReply->run = "true";
$ecDebitReply->reconciliationID = "02XFZ5EGJ868IMU2";
$ecDebitReply->debitRequestID = "5069499761916726603007";
$request->ecDebitReply = $ecDebitReply;
```

if any have idea why this issue has been arise and what is right call for tracking order.

Thanks